# Add slide state class to Revolution Slider container

Tags: jquery, revolution-slider

[LIVE DEMO](http://crystalweb.hu/lumindev2/lumin.html)

I have a static layer on top of my 3-slides revslider.
I want to change something in the static layer, when the slider reaches the third slide.

Currently the slider gives a ".current-sr-slide-visible" class to the li element when reaching it, but in this way I can't target the static layer with CSS since it's in the parent container...

This is my slider (simplified, just structural, see the above link to the full code):

```
<div class="revslider">
  <ul class="slides">
  ...
  <li id="slide3">...</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="static-layer">
  <svg class="logo"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**edit**: So I want to add any "slide3" ***indicator to any element but not the li element***. It could be good if I can put the indicator class on the ul, or the container, or the logo itself.

I tried this (this is working anywhere else on the page but not with the slider as desired, dont know why):

```
$(function(){
    if($('#slide3').hasClass('current-sr-slide-visible')) {
        $('.logo').addClass('white-logo');
    }
});
```

**edit2**: tried via revslider api, but something is wrong with this, not working... if you could see what is the problem with this, it could be a better solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var revapi = jQuery('.revslider').show().revolution(
    {
    // ...slider settings
    });

 // event for when slide is changed
 revapi.on('revolution.slide.onchange', function(e, data) {

    // slider changed
    var currentSlideNumber = data.slideindex;
    $('.revslider').addClass(currentSlideNumber);
});
});
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Slider Version:
 * jquery.themepunch.revolution.js - jQuery Plugin for Revolution Slider
 * @version: 4.6.4 (26.11.2014)

Comment: try using slide change event for this. Also mention the plugin version and give a link to the plugin site

Comment: any available live demo?

Comment: could you please tell me how? :) added version details

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="revslider">
  <ul class="slides">
  ...
  <li id="slide3">...</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="static-layer" class="logo">logo</div>
</div>
```

in your js you have type (.logo) that means a class is call logo. it might be the problem. good luck

Comment: `class="static-layer" class="logo"` really?

Comment: Sometimes it is not good to see a code in a small window sorry :D

Comment: did you try setAttribute("class","white_logo") ?

Comment: What i have mentioned is an INVALID MARKUP. You cannot have the same attribute two times.